# How Laravel handle URL routing with nginx?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I want to understand how to configure nginx for a laravel app, so that all URLs like `/api/v1/xxx` can be handled by laravel router?

PS: I can understand how laravel's router works, but I don't know why nginx would send all URL requests to laravel app. Which php file connects nginx with laravel's router? Is it the `index.php` inside laravel's public folder? If so, how it accomplished this mapping?

Comment: See this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04, you will find the nginx config example also

Comment: @TarunLalwani Is it the line `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` which do the mapping?

Comment: Yes, that is one. So you check if it is a file or a folder and if not then send it to index.php of laravel

Comment: @TarunLalwani That makes sense. Thx!